# Is it possible to have bnd provide warnings about superfluos or missing export-package entries?

Tags: java, osgi, bnd

To generate OSGi bundles I'm running bnd on each of my jar files with something like `java -jar biz.aQute.bnd-4.2.0.jar bundle.bnd`.
I have a .bnd file for each jar file and I always provide all the other jar files in the classpath.

I would like to know if there is a way to have bnd provide warnings for superfluous or missing export package entries.

I see that the Maven plugin can provide warnings for unnecessary packages:
https://maxrohde.com/2010/08/20/instructions-in-export-package-that-are-never-used/
However this is of no use to me because I don't use Maven.